# Is it possible to define a storage inside the pallet without config trait?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, storage, traits

Actually I want to define a storage without config trait but if I'm doing this then I'm getting lot of error. Is it possible?

```rust
/// Author of current block.
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type Author<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, u64, T::AccountId, OptionQuery>;
```

Need to define like this:

```rust
/// Author of current block.
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type Author = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, u64, AccountId, OptionQuery>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The config trait is used for the implementation of multiple traits during the macro expansion. Hence, this is not possible.

Why do you want to omit it anyways?